# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] equivalent in python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, web.py

I am a PHP developer and I used to get query string using   `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in PHP.

What is the Python 2.7 syntax for this?

```
import web
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path

urls = (
    '/voice', 'Voice'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())


class Voice:        
   def GET(self):
    WAV_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath("C:\Python27")),'wavfile.wav')

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.WavFile("C:\Python27\wavfile.wav") as source:
     audio = r.record(source) # read the entire WAV file
     output = r.recognize_google(audio)
     return output



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Using any particular framework?

Comment: No, updated the question.

Comment: I think the answer is _yes_ to a particular framework. It looks like you're using [`web.py`](http://webpy.org/)?

Comment: I am not aware of web.py as weill.

Comment: Your code includes `import web` (which [isn't in the Python 2 standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html#cap-w)) and the same `urls` / `app = web.application(urls, globals())` structure from the `web.py` tutorial. If your code really looks like this I'm fairly confident that it uses `web.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://webpy.org/cookbook/input

```
user_data = web.input()
```

Or use the urlparse library:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

```
from urlparse import urlparse

o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido?x=y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://example.com/?q=abc&p=123'
par = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [`web.py`](http://webpy.org/) (which your code suggests) you can use `web.ctx.query` (which includes the `?`) or `web.ctx.env['QUERY_STRING']`, which doesn't:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "web.ctx.env['QUERY_STRING']: {}".format(
            web.ctx.env['QUERY_STRING'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

See the [cookbook entry on `ctx`](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx) for more.